# RCpp long long unsigned int error issue

Tags: r, rcpp

I am a newbie to `Rcpp` and `C++`. I am trying to convert the following `R` code into RCpp.

```
library (compiler)
robzscore<-cmpfun(function(x) {
   byec <- sum(!is.na(x))
   byer <- rank(x, na.last="keep", ties.method="average") - 0.5
   as.data.frame(suppressWarnings(qnorm(byer/byec)), row.names=NULL)
})
```

I am struggling with writing the syntax for the part where i need to get the `ranks`. For example, this is what I wrote (in a separate `cpp` file that I am compiling using `sourceCpp`) based on other codes I found on SO as an equivalent of the `rank(x,...)` function in `R` assuming there are no `NA`s (and not handling ties):

```
 #include <Rcpp.h>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace Rcpp;

 template <typename T>
 std::vector<size_t> sort_indexes(const std::vector<T> &v) {

    // initialize original index locations
    std::vector<size_t> idx(v.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i!=idx.size();++i) idx[i]=i;

    // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
    std::sort(idx.begin(),idx.end(),[&v](size_t i1, size_t i2) {return v[i1]<v[i2];});

    // return the values  
    return idx;
  }


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector do_rank(NumericVector x) {
  std::vector<float> y=as<std::vector<float> >(x);
  return wrap(sort_indexes(y));
}
```

The error is get are:

1. `lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]` - followed by - `no matching function for call to 'sort(std::vector<long long unsigned int>::iterator, std::vector<long long unsigned int>::interator, sort_indexes(const std::vector<T> &) [ with T=float]::<lambda(long long unsigned int, long long u
   nsigned int)>)'` at the place where my code says `std::sort(idx.begin(),...)`.
2. `~/R/win-library/3.0/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/internal/wrap.h` : `invalid conversion from 'long long unsigned int' to 'SEXP' [-fpermissive]`.

I suspect the main issue with some error I made in the syntax I used to handle `Rcpp` (converting `Rcpp` to `C++` data structure or vice versa).

Can someone help me interpret the errors and/or what could be the right way?

Thanks,

Comment: This code compiles fine for me with `clang 3.5`. I suspect you will need to enforce `-std=c++0x` in your `Makevars` to get long long support from `Rcpp`.

Comment: @KevinUshey, how do I enforce `-std=c++0x` in my `Makevars`. Also, where is the `Makevars` usually located. I have primarily downloaded `Rtools` and the relevant packages within `RStudio`. Also, I am using Windows 7.

Comment: Generally speaking, lack of `long long` for lack of current C / C++ standards had been a thorn in our side for quite some time. Please do a little bit of googling and this will become clear, including how to set compiler options.